# Reproduce "no more processes" error

Tags: linux, bash

For academic purposes I would like to reproduce the error message   "no more processes" on my bash terminal. 
For example:

```
$cp file1.txp file2.txt
bash: no more processes
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This means the system is out of processes. Try running your command repeatedly while running the "bash fork bomb" in another window: https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+fork+bomb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reproduce that error, you can probably just start a fork bomb with the first parent exiting to get you back to your shell:

You'll probably want to ensure that your system applies a process limit before doing this otherwise you might just freeze the machine rather than get a shell where you can type stuff in and have it report that you don't have anymore processes left to do anything. You'll want to check out how many processes you are using normally first to figure out what limit to set.

In FreeBSD, you'll edit `/etc/login.conf` and change the `maxproc` on `default` and then set it to `unlimited` on `root`.

In most Linux distros, you'll edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and add a line at the bottom that looks like this: `*    hard     nproc     nnn`, where `nnn` is the number of processes.

Then `make` this simple fork bomb and run it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid) {
        // parent
        exit(0);
    } else {
        // child
        while (1) {
            fork();
        }
    }
    return 0; // we'll never get here
}
```